# Error trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop

Tags: 22.04, acpi, error-handling

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop using a USB device. When I tried to use Ubuntu live (before installing it) to see if I got errors I got this black screen.

[image: Errors]

Comment: Ignore them. If the live session desktop doesn't load then choose the "safe graphics" option and them make sure to (1) disable Secure Boot in UEFI and (2) select the option to install 3rd party drivers, codecs, etc.

Comment: I get stuck on "Updates and other software" (where do i have also selected to install 3rd party drivers, etc).
Is it normal that it takes so much time?

Comment: You should add more details, manufacturer of laptop, model, year, previous OS installed, if any...

Comment: The laptop is an AsusTek X541UV with an Intel i7-6500U. I installed a new SSD and removed the old HDD (with w10) from the laptop.